# systemLayoutSizeFittingSize gives incorrect size on first call

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I'm trying to calculate the height of the table view header based on the constraints. When I use the `layoutMarginsGuide` property I get the wrong size calling `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize`. If I pin the edges without using the margins guide, it works.

Here's the code:

```
class SomeVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

// MARK: Properties

let tableView = UITableView()
let headerView = UIView()
let circle = UIView()
let circleSize: CGFloat = 100



// MARK: Methods

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellID")
    view.addSubview(tableView)

    headerView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 20, 20, 20)
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.36)

    circle.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    circle.layer.cornerRadius = circleSize/2
    headerView.addSubview(circle)


    // Constraints for circle

    let margins = headerView.layoutMarginsGuide

    circle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    circle.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(margins.topAnchor).active = true
    circle.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(margins.bottomAnchor).active = true
    circle.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(margins.centerXAnchor).active = true
    circle.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(circleSize).active = true
    circle.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(circleSize).active = true


    // Constraints for tableView

    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.topAnchor).active = true
    tableView.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leadingAnchor).active = true
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.bottomAnchor).active = true
    tableView.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.trailingAnchor).active = true


    // Calculate size for headerView considering all constraints

    let size = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
    headerView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: size)
    tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView

    let size2 = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
    print("size:", size.height) // prints wrong height - 100.0
    print("size2:", size2.height) // prints correct height - 140.0
}


}
```

Why when I call `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` *second time* it gives correct size?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

So what I think is happening is that although your constraints are updating via your code, the actual layout of the tableView hasn't been re updated per your constraints. It will of course update before the view appears, but for use in calculations you'll want to update the layout within your viewDidLoad. Try

```
let size2 = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)

tableView.setNeedsLayout()
tableView.layoutIfNeeded()

print("size:", size.height) // prints wrong size - 100.0
print("size2:", size2.height) // prints correct size - 140.0
```

I'd call this before your print functions for testing.
With your tableView layout updated it should return the right size for frames and such for tableView and its subViews such as the header.

Comment: You added it right after updating the size and before printing it out?

Comment: Yeah @matthew-lawrence-bailey

Comment: prints -  size: 100.0 size2: 140.0

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize`, although it might be unrelated.

The safe area insets of a view are not yet set on the first call (they are all 0) to `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize`, maybe this applies to layout margins too. Subsequent calls will have the safe are insets setup correctly, which will result in the correct calculation.

I think in your case the only solution would be to stick to not using margin guides.